# How to save DOM manipulation changes?

Tags: angularjs

Part of the code in my controller deletes a DOM element:

```
MetrofficeApp.controller('EmployeesCtrl', function($scope) {
...
angular.element(deleteElem).remove();
$scope.$apply();
```

When I navigate away from this page using angular, and then come back to the same page where the deleted element is - the element **is visible again**.

What must I do besides $scope.$apply() to make the changes permanent (save DOM changes) between navigating pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the DOM.  Every time you navigate back to a page, all code is re-invoked and templates are recreated. So, it is correct behavior that the DOM is created again.

My guess is that you have some underlying model that is visualized by the DOM.  Rather than deleting components of the DOM, you should be deleting the part of the model that is visualized by the DOM (and pushing that change to the server).  This way, the next time you navigate to the DOM, the model is consistent and the deleted item is no longer shown.

And a smaller point, but still important: controllers should not be manipulating the DOM directly.  You should be creating directives for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some flag on the `scope` object which the angular js template can use to determine whether the show the dom element in question.

E.g.

```
// controller code
scope.shouldShowElement = some.flag;

// angular template
<div ng-show="shouldShowElement">...</div>
```

Angular templates have access to all the variables on the `scope` - if, at a later point, you do:

```
// controller code
scope.shouldShowElement = true;
scope.$apply();
```

Your template will update to reflect that change